# deleting multiple substrings of string

Tags: r, substring

I'm using R and I have a vector of strings with 1 and 2.

Examples of strings could be the following:

1. `"11111111******111"`
2. `"11111111111***2222222"`
3. `"1111*****22222**111*****1111"`

where `"*"` denote a gap.

I'm interested in deleting substrings of gaps shorter than a certain number **n**.

Example with sequences above:

I decided that **n**=3, so...

```
1. "11111111******111"
2. "111111111112222222"
3. "1111*****22222111*****1111"
```

In the second and third string the "function" deleted a substring of 3 gaps and 2 gaps, because I wanted to delete all substrings of gaps shorter or equal 3.

Comment: My expected output is the second list of strings, in which you can see the strings without the substrings of gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can do

```
n <-3
pat <- sprintf("(?<=[0-9])\\*{1,%d}(?=[0-9])", n)
gsub(pat, "", v1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "11111111******111"          "111111111112222222"         
#[3]  "1111*****22222111*****1111"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("11111111******111", "11111111111***2222222", "1111*****22222**111*****1111")
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. But if there was "3" instead of "*" would the code change so much?

Comment: Oh thanks! Do you know where I can find something to study the syntax of this function?

Comment: @jmarkov Here we create the pattern to match a set of `*` between 1 and 3 that follows numbers from 1-9  (`(?<=[0-9])`) and is succeeded by another set of numbers (`(?=[0-9])`).  It is regex lookarounds.  For understanding more about this, you can look at [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @akrun's answer:

```
x<- list("11111111******111",
"11111111111***2222222",
"1111*****22222**111*****1111")

lapply(x, function(x) gsub("(\\d)\\*{,3}(\\d)", "\\1\\2", x, perl = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('(?<=\\d)(\\*{1,3})(?=\\d)','',v1,perl=T)
[1] "11111111******111"          "111111111112222222"         "1111*****22222111*****1111"
```